# Converting Logarithmic Bases and Approximating Exponents

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, computer-science, logarithm

I'm studying for an algorithms final. There are some sample questions that I'd like to know how to solve. No calculators are permitted, and the methods used are more relevant to computer science than algebra. I'll try to be as specific as possible, because researching this has only led me to change-of-base formulas that require a calculator.

*What is (approximately) the Log base 2 of 130,000,000?*

*What is (approximately) the Log base 4 of 1,000,000?*

I'd also appreciate it if someone would explain base conversions without a calculator to me. Thank you. If this post is inappropriate, I'll remove it without hesitation.

Edit: Answers delivered in log(x)/log(r) will not be considered correct. Thank you.

Comment: Really? 128*1024*1024? 1024*1024?

Comment: This is really not helpful. I know this is a stupid question and probably a waste of your time, but if you know how to solve these types of problems I would greatly appreciate a walkthrough.

Comment: Uh... figure out which is closest that you *do* know.

Comment: How did _you_ solve it so quickly?

Comment: 1000 is almost 1024, and 130 is almost 128. The log2 of those are 10 and 7 respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is make your own table during the exam.

2, 4, 8, 32, 64, 128, 256,512, 1024, ....

Find the power of 2 that is closest to the value you looking for. If you are asked for Log2(1000), you'd see the closest is 1024 (2**10): Ans: 10.

Answer (score 0):

*log base r (x)* may be evaluated as `log(x)/log(r)`